# Latest version of Chromium installed with Homebrew does not play video - how to resolve?

Tags: macos, chromium, homebrew-cask

I recently installed Chromium on my Macbook Pro via Homebrew with:

```
brew install --cask chromium
```

and I'm finding that videos are not playing in the browser on a number of sites. All videos on CNN.com for example will not play. Are there any additional steps I need to take to get additional codecs installed?

Comment: That's because it's most likely not compiled with support for mp4 codecs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[By default, Chromium does not support proprietary codecs](https://chromium.woolyss.com/#html5-audio-video). You can get a build with all the codecs from [Woolyss](https://chromium.woolyss.com/), the builds with all the codecs enabled are tagged with "all-codecs+".

Or you can use [this homebrew tap](https://github.com/mtslzr/homebrew-marmaduke-chromium) to get the updates through homebrew.

Comment: Thanks so much @Ben - the Homebrew tap did the trick!